# How to make Java program that decrypts a message in a text document?

Tags: java, encryption, text, document

I want to make a program that will decrypt an encrypted message in a text document. The key is the alphabet in numbers reversed, eg a=26, b=25, c=24 and so on.

I already have the means to encrypt the message, but I'm having troubles finding a way to decrypt the message. I'd like to keep this as simple as possible, and I'm still a cheeky scrub when it comes to Java.

Comment: What specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try in the first place?

Comment: Without code, you're unlikely to get an answer. But to get you started, write it out by hand and think about what actions *you* are taking to decrypt it. Then think about how those actions translate into code.

Comment: Is this even possible? You could end up with a section of your string matching "242424" - how do you know what is C and what is W/Y?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even possible? You could end up with a section of your string matching "242424" - how do you know what is C and what is W/Y?

zackehh brought up a good point. One solution would be to add deliminators between the encoded numbers. For example, `242424` could become `2,4,24,2,4` and would no longer have ambiguity. This function operates under the assumption that you made that change:

```
public String decode(String decode) {
    String[] keyArray = {"z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s", "r", "q", "p", "o", "n", "m", "l", "k", "j", "i", "h", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a", "z"};
    String[] split = decode.split(",");

    StringBuilder decoded = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part : split) {
        int code = Integer.parseInt(part);
        decoded.append(keyArray[code - 1]);
    }

    return decoded.toString();
}
```

The code is pretty clean as it stands, but it doesn't have any error handling.

Problems would arise with non-regular inputs, such as `1,2,a,3` causing an exception when trying to parse `a`. Another exception would be thrown if `1,2,344` was passed in, for example, because `344` is not a valid key in your code (>26 is not a letter).

Adding error handing is left as an exercise to the reader, should you choose to go down the path of adding string deliminators.